# Implementing Bubble sort-two different ways or am I implementing different sorting algorithm altogether?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I was reading up on sorting algorithms, I finished selection and bubble sort and thought I should try to implement what I understood.It took me while to understand what I wrote intending to be selection sort(code snippet-1) wasn't implementing key features of selection sort at all(which is finding min of unsorted array and building sorted array one element at a time). So I wrote one more for selection sort(code snippet-3). But now, I'm curious about Snippet-1. Can someone tell me if it is bubble sort or not?

**Code Snippet-1**

```
public void sort(int[] arr) {
    // code snippet-1
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if(arr[i] > arr[j]){
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Code Snippet-2**

```
public void sort(int[] arr) {
    // code snippet-2
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n-1; j++) {
            if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]){
                int temp=arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Code Snippet-3**

```
public void sort(int[] arr) {
    // Code snippet-3
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int min = i;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
            if(arr[j] < arr[min]) {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[min];
        arr[min] = temp;
    }
}
```

---

Also, on a not so related account, can someone explain how the outer for loop condition (i.e `i<n` and `i<n-1`) doesn't affect the result in these cases? I only changed snippet-2's condition to `j<n-1` as it gave me `Arrayoutofbound` error because of arr[j+1] term. Yes, I saw the entire thing in debug mode and animations too but still not completely clear how to choose a condition. I know I'm missing something here.

Comment: Since it's "unrelated", when you do `arr[j] > arr[j+1]` you're going one past the current `j`. If you went all the way to the end, on the last element your code would throw that exception.\

Answer (score 1):

You have different approaches to bubble sort and the Arrayoutofbound exception is because of the comparison of n+1 element which is not there in the array.

In code snippet 2, you could also avoid one more loop by doing:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n-2; i++)
```